# aws cli credentials work on one server but not another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm having a strange issue with 1.10.65 where the same exact credentials work on one machine but not the other. It's perplexing. Both servers are using the same version of the cli. The problem server is running CentOS 7.2 and the one where the cli works is on CentOS 7.1. I don't think that should be the difference.  I added the credentials the same way on both using the aws configure --profile=foo command.

To demonstrate the problem, this is the error I get on the problem server:

```
[user@salt:~] #aws ec2 describe-regions --profile=jf-ops

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

On the working server I get the correct response.

```
[user@ops1:~] #aws ec2 describe-regions --profile=jf-ops
REGIONS ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com    ap-south-1
REGIONS ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com     eu-west-1
REGIONS ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com        ap-southeast-1
REGIONS ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com        ap-southeast-2
REGIONS ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com  eu-central-1
REGIONS ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com        ap-northeast-2
REGIONS ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com        ap-northeast-1
REGIONS ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com     us-east-1
REGIONS ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com     sa-east-1
REGIONS ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com     us-west-1
REGIONS ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com     us-west-2
```

As I mentioned I added the credentials to both the working and non-working servers in the same exact way. Through the configure subcommand:

```
[user@salt:~] #aws configure --profile=jf-ops
AWS Access Key ID [*********************]: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS Secret Access Key [********************]: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Default region name [us-east-1]:
Default output format [text]:
```

At one point I even copied the aws credentials and config file from the working server to the non-working server. And the error remained. :(

Below, please find the debug output of the command as it's run from the host where the cli isn't working correctly:

```
[user@salt:~] #aws ec2 describe-regions --profile=jf-ops --debug
2016-09-18 10:20:09,987 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.10.65 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.4.55
2016-09-18 10:20:09,987 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ec2', 'describe-regions', '--profile=jf-ops', '--debug']
2016-09-18 10:20:09,987 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x1a271b8>
2016-09-18 10:20:09,987 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x17566e0>
2016-09-18 10:20:09,991 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ec2/2016-04-01/service-2.json
2016-09-18 10:20:10,077 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.ec2: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x12cd488>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,077 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: ec2
2016-09-18 10:20:10,084 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ec2: calling handler <functools.partial object at 0x1a2f9f0>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,084 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.removals - DEBUG - Removing operation: import-instance
2016-09-18 10:20:10,085 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.removals - DEBUG - Removing operation: import-volume
2016-09-18 10:20:10,085 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ec2: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x1a31398>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,086 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ec2/2016-04-01/waiters-2.json
2016-09-18 10:20:10,089 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'dry-run', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x26bf050>), (u'no-dry-run', <awscli.arguments.BooleanArgument object at 0x26bf090>), (u'region-names', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x26bf0d0>), (u'filters', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x26bf110>)])
2016-09-18 10:20:10,089 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x1a276e0>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,090 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function _rename_arg at 0x1a68848>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,090 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function _rename_arg at 0x1a68938>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,090 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <functools.partial object at 0x1a2faa0>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,090 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x175f500>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,090 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x1940848>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,092 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ec2/2016-04-01/paginators-1.json
2016-09-18 10:20:10,092 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x192cd70>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,092 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x257fc50>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,092 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x26bf2d0>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,093 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event operation-args-parsed.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <functools.partial object at 0x161f470>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,093 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.describe-regions.dry-run: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x156ede8>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,093 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.describe-regions.region-names: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x156ede8>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.describe-regions.filters: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x156ede8>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.describe-regions.cli-input-json: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x156ede8>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.describe-regions.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x156ede8>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x26bf2d0>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ec2.describe-regions: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x257fc50>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2016-09-18 10:20:10,094 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2016-09-18 10:20:10,095 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2016-09-18 10:20:10,105 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: ec2
2016-09-18 10:20:10,114 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.ec2: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x12a3938>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,114 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2016-09-18 10:20:10,117 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting ec2 timeout as (60, 60)
2016-09-18 10:20:10,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.ec2.DescribeRegions: calling handler <bound method ParameterAlias.alias_parameter_in_call of <botocore.handlers.ParameterAlias object at 0x12c4e10>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,118 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=DescribeRegions) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': {'Action': u'DescribeRegions', 'Version': u'2016-04-01'}, 'url': u'https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.10.65 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.4.55'}, 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'has_streaming_input': False, 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x287df90>}, 'query_string': '', 'url_path': '/', 'method': u'POST'}
2016-09-18 10:20:10,118 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.ec2.DescribeRegions: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x287df10>>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,119 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2016-09-18 10:20:10,119 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

host:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20160918T142010Z

host;x-amz-date
426f0ef3e72959b3ca7e2830512478e82ee3489bfbbdcca9a97f6937a2b9faee
2016-09-18 10:20:10,119 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160918T142010Z
20160918/us-east-1/ec2/aws4_request
9de0742ab4b7bdcfea61335d7abc68f7dc03c2a1151a04f00e0d5cf1b4be21bb
2016-09-18 10:20:10,119 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
c2ee6219a5f56572726c5c3bacebd33879b0c49410e27b2cffb278339ca2319d
2016-09-18 10:20:10,124 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,125 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2016-09-18 10:20:10,150 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 None
2016-09-18 10:20:10,151 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Sep 2016 14:27:31 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}
2016-09-18 10:20:10,151 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>3bc05209-a868-4bd3-89cf-75cee9a1c43b</RequestID></Response>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,151 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.ec2.DescribeRegions: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x257fbd0>
2016-09-18 10:20:10,151 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2016-09-18 10:20:10,151 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 186, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 381, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 551, in __call__
    call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 675, in invoke
    **parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 494, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
2016-09-18 10:20:10,152 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

I'd appreciate some advice to get this working!

Comment: What policy does your user has?

Comment: Can you sync the clock on CentOS 7.2 machine and try? It is likely the clock on CentOS 7.2 is skewed which is making your signature invalid.

Comment: thanks! After syncing the clock on the 7.2 box, I was able to get aws iam commands working. However no change to aws ec2 commands. They're still broken with the same error. :(

Comment: The user has full Administrator rights.

Comment: port 443 outbound - is it enabled? the server may not be able to talk to AWS services to authenticate.

Comment: Are you using the IAM role for both EC2 instances? or are you not following best practice and using aws credentials file?

Comment: it will look for credentials in the current users home directory so make sure you have the credentials in the home directory for the right user. Also you should probably just set up the right IAM role access rather than storing the credentials in plain text.

Comment: I had this same issue, and fixing the clock fixed everything for all types of AWS calls (including ec2).